# samba shared folder and mounted disk

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

Technically I only want to setup a samba shared folder.

Situation:
With CentOS7 and samba I can successfully setup a shared folder but even if I change the create and directory mask, the read only and writeable flags, I am not able to write from my windows client. For testing I also set everything of the path to 777.
My second problem, the bigger problem, is that if I change the path of the shared folder to a mounted disk I am not able to connect to the shared folder form my windows client anymore.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem? Or do anyone know something that can maybe help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody after me.
Please pay attention about SELinux.

More Information:
http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page